# Using onclick on checkbox to redirect to another page

Tags: javascript

I want to direct the user to another page when they check a checkbox. This is what I tried.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cheque_status" value="0" id="chequeList" onclick="myfunc()"/>

            <iframe style="display:none;">
                <script>
                    function myfunc(){
                        if(document.getElementById("chequeList").checked= true) {
                                location.href = "/index.cfm";
                            }
                    }
                </script>
            </iframe>
```

Basically what I am trying to do is, if there is any `onclick` on the checkbox, then it should redirect users to that index.cfm page. However, it doesn't work for me.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the `= true` in your test. It's an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: Use a link. Use a real link. Checkboxes are not links and shouldn't behave like links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've provided the `<script>` as alternative content to an `<iframe>` which doesn't have a `src` and isn't displayed.

Remove the iframe.

(Also fix your `=` in the JS: You need a comparison, not an assignment).

Comment: I removed the iframe and also the `=` and it works perfectly. Thank you.